# Comparing gam models using ti( )

Tags: generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I want to compare gam models including interaction with simpler models.
For interaction models, I used `gam(Y~ti(X1) + ti(X2) + ti(X1,X2))`.
Removing the interaction, the models end as `Y~ti(X1) + ti(X2)`.

How those models compare with models with the form `Y ~ s(X1) + s(X2)` ?

In my case, the former (i.e. `ti()` form) have a better AIC value than those with `s()`.

Should I keep the `ti()` form or use only the `s()` form when I have no interaction ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Is your question about R functions, or is it just about the underlying models? As phrased I think you're trying to ask about the underlying models, but as formatted it seems like it's about the R implementation of them. If it is about R, you should specify which package you're using (the `gam` function exists in more than one package)

Comment: @Glen_b Sorry for the delay ... fieldwork with no reliable web access... You are right my question is mainly about the underlying models. This is the first time I use interactions into a gam models. I use the gam fonction from the mgcv package, and the use of ti() seems the best way to consider interactions. However, I have never seen the use of ti() in models without interactions ... that the main reason of my question.